# '$(this)' within a method called by a button makes the browser unresponsive

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a Rails view file in slim format, I have:

```
= button_tag("Press me", onclick: "$.foo();")
```

which results in rendering:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" onclick="$.foo();">Press me</button>
```

With the press of this button, I just want to execute a jQuery method without making any kind of request to the Rails server. In a JavaScript file to be called, I confirmed that the corresponding method is correctly called by doing:

```
$.foo = function(){
  alert('foo');
};
```

which worked. Within this method, I actually want to access the (jQuerified) button object that has been pressed. I changed the method to:

```
$.foo = function(){
  alert($(this));
};
```

and this makes the browser hang when I press the button.

What is wrong with my code, and/or what is the correct way within the jQuery method to call the button object that has been pressed?

Comment: Use `console.log()` for logging instead of `alert()`, As per current implementation of `$.foo()`, `this` will refer to `window` object. I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler instead of `onclick`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks. You are right. I just had forgotten that.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `<button type="button">` for this rather than a *submit* button?

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah. That's right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Satpal in the comment, I was reminded that `this` in the method as in my original code will refer to `window` object. And as was pointed out by @muistooshort, I need to specify `type: "button"` to avoid the request being sent to the Rails server.

I changed my code to:

**View file**

```
= button_tag("Press me", type: "button", onclick: "$.foo(this);")
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.foo = function(target){
  alert($(target));
};
```

and I got what I want.

Comment: If you want you can modify the code i.e. `$.fn.foo = function(){
  alert($(this));
};` and use it like `onclick: "$(this).foo();"`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, that is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an event listenet and get `event.currentTarget`:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
        var btn = $(event.currentTarget);
        // ...
    });
</script>
```